# How to scp-and-ssh with specifying host twice?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, scp

I frequently do this kind of thing:

```
scp somefile me@host:/some/path
ssh me@host
```

Typing out `me@host` twice can be irksome. We (or at least `bash`) can grab that last argument with `!:$`, but that (`me@host:/some/path`) is not exactly what `ssh` wants.

So, how can I `scp` a file and then immediately `ssh` to that same host--without having to explicitly specify the host more than once?

Please note that I am not interested in saving the host in a variable eg `PLACE=me@host; scp somefile at $PLACE:/some/path; ssh $PLACE`.

Comment: I am not interested in saving the host in a var eg

    PLACE=me@host;
    scp somefile at $PLACE:/some/path;
    ssh $PLACE

Comment: You should [edit that information into the question](http://superuser.com/posts/963165/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `ssh` to host used in previous `scp` command

Well, since per your comment storing `me@host` in variable is out<sup>1</sup>; we'll have to do it another, cleverer way:

```
$ scp somefile me@host:/some/path
$ ssh "${_%%:*}"
```

This will `ssh` you to `me@host`.

### Explanation

`$_` recalls the last argument to the previous command. The `%%` construct deletes the *longest* match from the *back* of the string. `:*` matches everything from a colon (`:`) onwards.

So `"${_%%:*}"` deletes everything from `:` onwards in the previous command (ie `:/some/path`) leaving `me@host`.

Tested using `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release`

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>If you ask me, doing `hn=me@host` and then using `hn` in the `scp` and `ssh` commands is easier than using `"${_%%:*}"`. Particularly if `me@host` is used quite often it can be advantageous to definite this in `.bashrc` (and/or `host` in `~/.ssh/config`) for easy use; but this is up to individual preference.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Write yourself a script - e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

src_file=$1
dst=$2

test -n "$src_file" || exit 1
test -n "$dst" || exit 1

dst_login=${dst%%:*}

if scp $src_file $dst; then
    echo
    echo "scp succeeded, starting ssh session ..."
    ssh $dst_login
else
    echo "scp failed. Not stargin ssh session."
    exit 1
fi
```

Save the above into a file, make it executable (`chmod a+x scp-and-ssh`), runit (`./scp-and-ssh somefile me@somehost:somefile`).

Btw.: You can set the remote username in your `~/.ssh/config` in a `Host` section. This way you only need to specify the remote hostname and can leave the `me@` away.

Answer (score 1):

> Typing out `me@host` twice can be irksome.

This is what is `ssh_config` for. You can store username and alias for your host:

```
Host short
  Hostname host
  User me
```

which will save you typing and you end up with only `scp file short:path; ssh short`. Probably not the answer you are searching, but

- there is automatic completion
- much less hack then alias or variable
- seems to me easier than typing some weird characters ;)